# How do we handle harmful answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

Every now and then I stumble upon an answer that is more or less harmful when followed.

I'm talking about these "What's the shortcut for quicksaving?" -> "Alt+F4" answers (well obviously in a bigger scale). Sometimes in order to get a game or something in a game to work you have to modify and/or delete certain files and a lot of questions here on arqade focus on games with a huge modding community which requires actions like deleting and/or coding even more often.

How should we handle or flag these harmful answers to burn them before they can do any harm? I mean yes we are in the stackexchange community and we have a fair amount of people who work in IT but there are also people on here who would try to quicksave with alt+f4 if they read it on a site like this.

Comment: Troll answers should be flagged, and if you have the privilege, voted to delete.

Comment: I think it would also be a good idea to leave a comment, which warns other users and explains why this is harmful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers that are intentionally misleading and harmful should simply be removed, flagging them as abusive would be justified in my opinion. This would apply to answers like "try `rm -rf /`" and similar ones.

Answers that are more dangerous than they appear, but likely well-intentioned should be edited. In minor cases, commenting is enough.